# Installing private packages in app engine from a google artifact registry

Tags: google-app-engine, pip

I am trying to modularize our code, and running into difficulties installing private packages on app engine.
We have a repository on GCP in the same project, so I would think this is not too difficult.

My requirement.txt looks like:

```
--extra-index-url=https://us-central1-python.pkg.dev/myproject/my-python-repo/simple/
Flask==2.0.1
my-new-package
```

I can pip install the package locally, and it uses the `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth` package to authenticate.

The deployment fails with:

```
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 218, in ask_input
    return input(message)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

This is clearly pip asking for a username, where i
Is google's own keyring package not available in its own environment? [This](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build) Suggests so. Of course adding it to requirements.txt has no effect, as it is too late.

How can I install packages properly?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? This worked in cloud run for me, and now I'm thinking of using app engine.

Comment: I store base64 encoded credentials.json in $GCLOUD_KEY_FILE and then run this in the pipeline

`poetry config http-basic.pygcp _json_key_base64 $GCLOUD_KEY_FILE`

`poetry export --without-hashes --with-credentials -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt`

The resulting requirements.txt has the required extra index url for the private repo named 'pygcp' in pyproject.toml.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to:

```
--extra-index-url=_json_key_base64:KEY@us-central1-python.pkg.dev/myproject/my-python-repo/simple/
```

Where KEY is the result of `base64 -w 0 < credentials.json`

Of course this then requires some rewriting of the requirements.txt file in your deployment pipeline to ensure service account credentials are secured in repository variables.