# pip install package from Artifact Registry from github action

Tags: github-actions, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to install a package via pip as part of my github CI/CD but facing issues.
I successfully published my package on the artifact registry. I can see it when i run

```
gcloud artifacts versions list --package=PACKAGE
```

I have given access to the registry for the identity pool with

```
gcloud artifacts repositories add-iam-policy-binding PACKAGE_NAME \
--location=europe-west9 --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/${REPO}" --role=roles/artifactregistry.admin
```

The setup of the identity pool should be fine since github is able to access other resources (in my case pub sub)

But the workflow fails with

```
pip install --index-url https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/path-to/simple/ PACKAGE
```

with the error below

```
Looking in indexes: https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/ynstant-dev/ynstant-utils/simple/
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 44, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 297, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 890, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 831, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/sources.py", line 194, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 791, in process_project_url
    index_response = self._link_collector.fetch_response(project_url)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 461, in fetch_response
    return _get_index_content(location, session=self.session)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 364, in _get_index_content
    resp = _get_simple_response(url, session=session)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 135, in _get_simple_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 520, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 710, in send
    r = dispatch_hook("response", hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/hooks.py", line 30, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 500, in handle_401
    username, password, save = self._prompt_for_password(parsed.netloc)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 455, in _prompt_for_password
    username = ask_input(f"User for {netloc}: ") if self.prompting else None
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 251, in ask_input
    return input(message)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
User for europe-west9-python.pkg.dev: 
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I am able to run this command from my terminal and it install the package fine.
What am i missing?

Comment: no thanks for replying but the command is wrong. The parameter packages_to_install applies to the decorator, which is what the OP of the link you provided is having issues with

Comment: Can you share the minimal reproducible steps? What do you have in [`https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev`](https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev) and where did you find that package?  Or is it created by you? Also check with this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/store-python).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this [Github Link](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/9011#issuecomment-1534273913) Can you try particularly giving the `packages_to_install` tag like below:

> `pip install --index-url https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/path-to/simple/ PACKAGE` as `pip install --index-url https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/path-to/simple/ packages_to_install=PACKAGE`

Also based on your logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File [...] username, [...]_prompt_for_password [...] ask_input return input(message) EOFError: EOF when reading a line.
```

Can you try to install a pip package from Artifact Registry and to work with the workflow, Try with the below steps:

1. Create an Artifacts Registry Python repository
2. Create a Composer environment (everything is default)
3. Create a service account
4. Grant permissions in Artifacts Registry for this account
5. Download JSON key for a service account and encode it in base64 using command `cat service-account.json | base64`
6. Upload `pip.conf` to `/config/pip/pip.conf` in Composer GCS bucket

**Note:** Contents of this file as it is mentioned in [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#sa-key),  where KEY is a string generated on a step #5.

Please also have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69130681/18265702).